# How to align a picture to the bottom of another picture?

Tags: html, css

How to align the raccoon picture so it appear at the right bottom of the big round picture? As it is at the image.

I tried background-position: bottom right; as well as position: absolute; but it doesn't work.

See the code below.

Thank You.

[image]

```css
.p-i--1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-3930.jpg);
}
.p-i {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: bottom right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
.p-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.p-wrap {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.pic-wrap {
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.p_pic-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.fernomortuary.com/~/media/products-mortuary/swatches/Swatch_Burgundy.ashx?w=122);
  background-position: center;
  float: left;
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.p-description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.p-name {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-1">
  <div class="p-i--1 p-i"></div>
  <div class="pic-wrap">
    <a class="p_pic-1" href="index.html"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="p_wrap">
    <h4 class="p-name">Some text</h4>
    <p class="p-description">Some very very very very long description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can the CSS code and HTML markup be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the smaller picture within `.pic-wrap`. Give it an `absolute` position and align it using `bottom` and `right` properties:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mexmxqxe/3/)

CSS Changes made:

```
.pic-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.p-i { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And if you want the white border around the small image:

```
.p-i { 
   border: 3px solid white;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mexmxqxe/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `bottom` and `right` property to your absolute element like this:

```
.p-i {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: bottom right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

Here's a snippet with the above codes:

```css
.p-i--1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-3930.jpg);
}
.p-i {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-position: bottom right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 50px;
}
.p-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.p-wrap {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.pic-wrap {
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.p_pic-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.fernomortuary.com/~/media/products-mortuary/swatches/Swatch_Burgundy.ashx?w=122);
  background-position: center;
  float: left;
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.p-description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.p-name {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-1">
  <div class="p-i--1 p-i"></div>
  <div class="pic-wrap">
    <a class="p_pic-1" href="index.html"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="p_wrap">
    <h4 class="p-name">Some text</h4>
    <p class="p-description">Some very very very very long description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6sxLj3hL/
Your hard coded height on the container wasn't necessary so I removed it.

```
.p-i--1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-3930.jpg);
}
.p-i {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-position: bottom right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float:right

}
.p-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.p-wrap {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.pic-wrap {
    width: 122px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.p_pic-1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.fernomortuary.com/~/media/products-mortuary/swatches/Swatch_Burgundy.ashx?w=122);
    background-position: center;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
.p-description {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.p-name {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I rearranged your HTML a bit

```
<div class="p-1">
    <div class="pic-wrap"> 
        <a class="p_pic-1" href="index.html"></a>
        <div class="p-i--1 p-i"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="p_wrap">
         <h4 class="p-name">Some text</h4>
        <p class="p-description">
            Some very very very very long description
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```